# React Native conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I currently have an IMAGES array that is supposed to display images if the index exists. With the current implementation, I have the images are being displayed if an index with an image exists and for index without images, a black screen gets displayed.

How do I change my code so that if an image doesn't exist it does not get added to the array?

Here is my code:

```
const IMAGES = [
  post.images[1]
    ? {
        url: post.images[1].url,
      }
    : [],
  post.images[2]
    ? {
        url: post.images[2].url,
      }
    : [],
  post.images[3]
    ? {
        url: post.images[3].url,
      }
    : [],
  post.images[4]
    ? {
        url: post.images[4].url,
      }
    : [],
  post.images[5]
    ? {
        url: post.images[5].url,
      }
    : [],
  post.images[6]
    ? {
        url: post.images[6].url,
      }
    : [],
  post.images[7]
    ? {
        url: post.images[7].url,
      }
    : [],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
const IMAGES = [];
post.images && post.images.map(image => {
    if(image && image.url) {
        IMAGES.push({url: image.url})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let IMAGES = [];
post?.images &&
  post.images.length > 0 &&
  post.images.map((eachImage, index) => {
    if ("url" in eachImage) {
      IMAGES.push(eachImage.url);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi BHARAT, How do i add each url in {} then push to IMAGES array?

Comment: I want it to look like this `[{
        url: "https//1",
      },
      {
        url: "https//2",
      },]` instead of this `[
        url: "https//1",
        url: "https//2",]`

Comment: IMAGES.push({url: eachImage.url})

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp).

```
> post={}
 {}

> post.images ? post.images.filter( ele => ele.url) : null
 null

> post={ images:[ {}, {"url":"abc"}, {}, {"url": "cde"} ]}
 {images: Array(4)}

> post.images ? post.images.filter( ele => ele.url) : null
  (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```js
const posts = {
    images: [
      {
        url: "https//1",
      },
      {
        url: "https//2",
      },
      {},
      {
        url: "https//3",
      },
      null,
      {
        url: "https//4",
      },
    ],
  };
  
const images = posts.images.map((item) => (item && item.url ? {url:item.url} : []));
console.log(images)
```

Comment: Hi Muhammed, is the extra {} in middle of images array by accident?

Comment: it's not by accident it's just for testing, because in the array we can find null or empty objects. that's a generic solution

Comment: let me give it a try and get back to you